# How to change the type of a numpy array from string to bool?

Tags: arrays, numpy, boolean

I have a numpy array where it is an array of strings that say 'true' and 'false'. How would I change it into a boolean array? Code:

```
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np

cat = '/home/myname/catalogue.csv'  
cat = Table.read(cat, format="ascii")

check = np.array(cat['IsTrue'])
```

The column 'check' currently prints out:

```
   ['true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'false', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'false', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'false',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
   'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true']
```

Again how would I convert this array of strings into a boolean array?

Comment: Show us the format of the input CSV.  Chances are you can read it directly to booleans.

Comment: @JohnZwinck How would I do that (read it in as a boolean array)? The catalogue is just an astropy table.

Comment: Show us the format of the input CSV.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Convert String Representation of Boolean Array To Boolean Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944798/numpy-convert-string-representation-of-boolean-array-to-boolean-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following and it should work,

```
np.array(check)=='true'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `check` is a numpy array

```
check = np.array(['true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true',
                  'true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'true'])
```

then you can use `eval()`, `capitalize()` and `tolist()` combined into the one-liner

```
check = np.array([eval(i.capitalize()) for i in check.tolist()])

print(check)
print(type(check[0]))
```

Output:

```
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
  <class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works:

```
check = (check == "true")
```